# how to pass a array from ajax to php with some other variable

Tags: jquery

Guys i want to pass an array (got from checkbox) with some other variable.

```
function some_function(user_id,add_remove_id,which_page) {
    //getting the array
    var allVals = [];   
    $('#friend_id_saf :checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    var type=3;
    var data = 'user_id=' + user_id+'&add_remove_id='+add_remove_id+'&type='+type;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"add_rem_friend.php", 
        //*****************************************
        // how should i send the data to php
        data:data,{myarray:allVals}, 
        //******************************************          
        success:function(html) {
            if (which_page==='incoming-request') {
                $('#'+add_remove_id).html(html);

            } else if(which_page ==='profile-details') {
                $('#div_status').html(html);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

how should i send the array with other data?

```
data:data,{myarray:allVals},
```

please help me.

Comment: Convert your array to a JSON string - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: `$('#friend_id_saf :checked').each(function() {` seems you're using duplicate ID's, ID's should be unique!

Comment: I guess you can refer to this SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377585/passing-array-value-from-jquery-ajax-to-php-function-call.

Comment: instead of merging them like this `var data = 'user_id=' + user_id+'&add_remove_id='+add_remove_id+'&type='+type;` , better place them all in ajax call like this .`data:{'user_id':user_id,'add_remove_id':add_remove_id,'type':type,'myArray:'allVals'}`. this is simplest way of passing the values in ajax call.

Comment: Make a Fiddle with your html. Guys, always try to save others time.

Comment: @dreamweiver getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  
 
 data:{'search_user_id':search_user_id,'type':type,'myArray':al‌​lVals},  
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL            
     
what to do man?

Comment: @MDTAHMIDHOSSAIN:Sorry man, i told you the wrong way. try this way `data: {
    start: 'value1',
    end: 'value 2'
}`. let me know if you are still getting error

Comment: With respect to above comment ,**value1** & **value2** are  string constanst,hence enclosed in singles quotes. if you wanna pass variables, then use the variable name without any quotes.

Comment: @dreamweiver
i have fixed it now. thank you very much.

Comment: ok, are you saying what i suggested worked out for u ?

Comment: yup it was. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its as simple as just merging the maps.

```
data: $.extend(data, {myarray:allVals});
```

or if its simple set it before the call and just pass data.

```
#before .ajax
data[myarray] = allVals

#inside of .ajax
data: data
```

Comment: data: $.extend(data, {myarray:allVals}); should be in ajax call?